# Limit proof using inequality manipulations

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that $(x^4+y^4)^.5$ is less than or equal to $x^2+y^2$, and I've gotten stuck after a few different attempts at manipulation. Any insight?

Update: I solved it using a method I'd already tried. Thanks for the commentors who took the time to look at my problem!

Comment: Try squaring both. :)

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of your ideas.

Comment: @rygami the aim of the problem is to begin with the left side and through a series of manipulations end with the right side, I have to sort out the middle portion

Answer (score 1):

Binomial theorem

$x^4+y^4 \le (x^2 + y^2)^2 = x^4 + y^4 + ... $

Now prove are the rest of the terms positive? And does squaring hold the inequality? (Both $x^4+y^4$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are positive)

Answer (score 0):

The answer I attempted earlier substituting $y^4 $with k and $x^4$ with j and using the triangle inequality in fact worked. I answered commenter Tim Raczkowski earlier as a comment, and since the method worked I've since deleted the comment in order to reduce redundancy with this answer post.